# How to layout 4 Items keeping one at center

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am almost new to SwiftUI and I am not able to properly manage the component layout.

I started with this simple layout:

[image]

using this code:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        HStack {
            Text("Item 1")
                .border(Color.white)
                .padding(.leading, 20)

            Spacer()

            Text("Item 2")
                .border(Color.white)
                .alignmentGuide(.hCenter, computeValue: { d in d[HorizontalAlignment.center] })

            Spacer()

            Text("Item 3")
                .border(Color.white)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.blue)
}
```

Now I need to add another item between Item 1 and Item 2, keeping Item 2 at the center of the screen.

I thought to use another HStack in this way:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        HStack {

            HStack {
                Text("Item 11")
                .border(Color.white)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)

                Text("Item 12")
                .border(Color.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
            }
            .frame(minHeight: 40)
            .background(Color.yellow)

            Spacer()

            Text("Item 2")
                .border(Color.white)
                .alignmentGuide(.hCenter, computeValue: { d in d[HorizontalAlignment.center] })

            Spacer()

            Text("Item 3")
                .border(Color.white)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.blue)
}
```

Unfortunately, the result is not what I expected.

[image]

- Item 2 is not centered anymore
- Adding a Spacer between Item11 and Item12 (to keep them well spaced) is even worst because Item2 moves even further to the right.

I played with GeometryReader and HorizontalAlignment without much success.

Which is the right approach to layout components in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1):

For the question how it is formulated here is the simplest solution (however, of course, real expectations might differ)

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Item 11")
                    .border(Color.white)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)

                Text("Item 12")
                    .border(Color.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
            }
            .frame(minHeight: 40)
            .background(Color.yellow)

            Spacer()
            Text("Item 3")
                .border(Color.white)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
        .background(Color.red)
        .overlay(Text("Item 2")             // << the only item in overlay,
                 .border(Color.white))      // << so centered

    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.blue)
}
```